# How do i stop webpack overwriting existing files/overwrite changes with github repo?

Tags: node.js, git, webpack

I have a project which uses vue-cli and webpack. I cant get the project to work if i pull it from the github repo, so what i have to do is initialise vue and webpack again inside the directory with `vue init webpack [directory name]` and it will initialise the existing directory again.

The issue is that when webpack initialises the existing directory again, it overwrites important files, for example, the `src/router/index.js` file that comes with webpack.

This would be fine if i could just overwrite the files that webpack changed after initialising the project again after pulling it from the github repo, but i can't workout how to do that.

So how do i do either of these two options:

---

1. Overwrite the changes that webpack made to my project after i pull the project from the github repo?

---

2. How do i make webpack initialise an existing project without overwriting the existing files?

Comment: This sounds like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). The actual issue here is that you think you need to run `vue init webpack` over and over. _That's_ what you should be asking about.

Comment: @Chris I have tried just doing `vue init webpack` once, but after literally days of staring at a command prompt ive realised it only works if i initialise it again after `git pull`, but files are overwritten which i don't want to be.

Comment: My point is that you should ask about your _real_ problem: "`git pull` somehow breaks my Vue.js app", not your workaround.

Comment: I know that i need to get the files that were overwritten by webpack from my github onto my device but when i type in `git pull` or any other variation git bash claims that everything is up to date, even though the github repo has router files with the correct routes in and my local copy just has the default route provided by webpack.

Comment: I have asked about git pull breaking it and i couldn't find an answer so im trying to find a solution using a method that i'd rather not do.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550307/why-does-my-webpack-project-fail-to-build-when-i-clone-from-github-repo)  There is my other question where i tried to find an answer to the git pull problem.

Comment: @Chris do you know how to fix any of these issues?

Comment: Is this repo public? If so, can you share the link? Sounds like something's not being committed to the repo.